# how do i send an object in a protocol delegate method to get a notification and an object to manipulate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

```
@protocol VideoDelegate <NSObject>

 @optional
-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSObject*)currencyInfo;
-(void)videoPlayBackDidStart;
```

i want to send a json object with the `videoPlayBackDidFinish` so I can recieve the notification that it is done and i can optionally use parts of that object

ex:`object.valueOfWhatever`

Comment: I disagree with the question being closed!!  I knew exactly what he was asking and how to answer it  Does he just need needs to add "HOW can I" instead of "I want to"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the JSON to a dictionary and then send it as the userInfo in the notification:

```
NSDictionary *quickDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, key1, nil];

NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:kVideoDidFinishNotification object:self userInfo:quickDict];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

I'm not sure how to make the videoPlayBackDidFinish be the receiver of the message without doing something like this in your delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:kVideoDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

and then in the method to get to the dictionary:

```
-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *jsonInfo = [notification userInfo];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, im going to try this now!